# How to solve file upload error in Postman?

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-web-api2, postman, asyncfileupload

I use file upload with webapi in my project. I am testing with Postman. However, **Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()** always returns false.

Postman screenshot:

[image]

[image]

FileUploadController Code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UserImageUpload()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            var userImageUploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(CommonParameters.UserProfileImageServerPath);
            var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(userImageUploadPath);
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

            var files = new List<string>();
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in streamProvider.FileData)
            {
                files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.ErrorFormat("An error occured in UserImageUpload() Method - Class:FileUploadController - Message:{0}", exception);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried file upload with fiddler. it worked.

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. Did you get to find the problem?

Answer (score 10):

This is Postman bug. Try removing the Content-Type header. When sending the actual Post, the browser will automatically add the proper header and create the boundary.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to mention Content-Type in headers in Postman, I tried sending attachments without Content-Type it works fine for me.
When i used `Content-Type: multipart/formdata` it throws an error saying "Could not get any response". Postman sends your file attachments also with `Content-Type →text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 2):

There are few things to consider:

1. Don't send any **Content Type** Header if you are using **Postman**
2. Specify the form-data **Key** for your choosen file in **Body (form-data)** (PFB Screenshot for your reference)

[image: Please check below postman screenshot for your reference.]

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncheck Content-Type if you have it checked, and let Postman add it for you, like in this picture:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might by a bit late.  I encountered the same error in ARC and resolved by providing a name for the file field (after the blue check mark on your second screenshot)